# filemaker find specific value with a dropdown menu

Tags: search, filemaker

I have created a FM-DB with some drop down fields. The problem is, that when I go into search mode and choose e.g. the number "1" in the drop down field and start the search, then I get also all records with the number 11, 12, 13 ... in that particular field.

Is there a way to tell FM to search only for an exact value? Since it is a Dropdown I can't enter the = before the value.

Thx for your help.
Dan

Comment: Does your actual use case involve numbers, or is that just your example? If your use case actually involves numbers, consider changing the field type to Number from Text.

Comment: thx, my bad.... had the field set to text. (don't ask my why i did that?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields that are type 'text' will search as you have indicated above: matching the first characters of the search string. For example, searching in a text field for 'sta' will find 'stack' and 'stacy' and 'stairs'. In your example the search is for a leading '1' in a text string, which will find '1', '10', '11', etc.

Changing your field to type 'number' should provide the numeric search that you are expecting, where a search for 1 will only find values equal to 1.